# MAUI and Entity Framework Core compatibility problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022, maui

Every time I try to implement Entity Framework Core (I tried SQL and SQLite) into a MAUI application, I get an error from VS2022:

> DEP1600: The list of content files in the recipe file "****\win10-x64\MauiEfTest2.build.appxrecipe" is missing or malformed.

When I delete the file and rebuild the whole solution, this file is recreated and the build succeeds without any error message, but as soon as I try to run the application this error message reappears.

Before introducing the Entity Framework Core packages, the application compiled and ran just fine.

I use :

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022, Version 17.3.6
- MAUI on .NET 6.0
- Entity Framework Core 6.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some relative issues on installing Entity Framework Core related nuget.

You can follow them up by the following links:

[Build error APPX1101 (.NET 6 WinUI 3 and Microsoft.EntityFramework.Tools)](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1856).

[EntityFrameworkCore install errors](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7436).

You can try the following workaround:

open your `.csproj` and make the changes indicated below:

```
+ <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.1" />
- <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.1">
-    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
-    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
- </PackageReference>
```

Refer: [issuecomment-1006882973](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1856#issuecomment-1006882973)